# order values in categorical variable using `transform` function

Tags: r

I have a test dataset like this:

```
table(spamday)  
FR MO SA SU TH TU WE  
30 96  9  9 45 60 51
```

with structure:

```
str(spamday)  
'data.frame':   300 obs. of  1 variable:
$ SPAMreceived: Factor w/ 7 levels "FR","MO","SA",..: 2 5 5 5 6 2 6 2 2 6 ...
```

and my goal is to use the `transform` function to make the categorical variable an ordered factor with the order imposed with `levels` directive

so I run the following code:

```
spamday <- transform(spamday, SPAMreceived <- factor(SPAMreceived, levels = c("MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA", "SU"), ordered = TRUE))
```

and guess what? nothing happens... still the same when `table` used:

```
table(spamday)  
FR MO SA SU TH TU WE  
30 96  9  9 45 60 51
```

I am confused... what am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hard sometimes to keep track of when to use `<-` and when to *not* use it, but this is a case in which you do *not* want to use it. In other words, simply changing your code to the following should do the trick:

```
spamday <- transform(spamday, SPAMreceived = factor(SPAMreceived, 
    levels = c("MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA", "SU"), ordered = TRUE))
```

Here's a small example:

```
set.seed(1)
spamday <- data.frame(SPAMreceived = sample(c("FR", "MO", "SA", "SU", "TH", "TU", "WE"),
                                            50, replace = TRUE))
table(spamday$SPAMreceived)
# 
# FR MO SA SU TH TU WE 
#  5  7  7  6  9 10  6

temp <- transform(spamday, SPAMreceived = factor(SPAMreceived, 
    levels = c("MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA", "SU"), ordered = TRUE))
table(temp$SPAMreceived)
# 
# MO TU WE TH FR SA SU 
#  7 10  6  9  5  7  6
```

---

Alternatively, you don't even need to necessarily create an ordered factor column. Just sort your table in the final stage :)

```
table(spamday$SPAMreceived)[c("MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA", "SU")]
# 
# MO TU WE TH FR SA SU 
#  7 10  6  9  5  7  6
```